# C++ timestamp validation from string

Tags: c++, date, validation, timestamp

I have string with timestamp and I would like to check that value is conform to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601, but available solutions do not give full validation.

I tried in boost library wrong date like this :

```
std::cout << boost::posix_time::from_iso_string("20021012T255920218")<< '\n';
```

and I receive corrected date in output like:
`output: 2002-Oct-13 01:59:20.180000`
boost library overflows hours to next day instead of giving some error.

Additionally I checked chrono with other wrong date like:

```
{
 std::tm tm = {};
 std::stringstream ss("Feb 30 2014 21:35:34");
try{
ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm));
std::time_t ep = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
std::cout << "ep " << std::ctime(&ep);
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{ std::cout << e.what();
}
```

and I receive corrected date in output like:
`output: Sun Mar  2 21:35:34 2014`
chrono overflows days, in case of wrong hours it gives zeros instead of giving some error (Fri Jan 24 00:00:00 2014).
I can't use other external libraries like https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date, because of internal requirements.

Comment: You might convert back to a string and check if it's identical to the original input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `std::regex_match` and use a regular expression that only matches with valid dates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string date_string = "20021012T255920218";
    std::regex e("^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])([0-5][0-9])([0-5][0-9])(.[0-9]+)?(Z)?$");
    bool valid_ISO_861 = std::regex_match(date_string , e);
}
```